# Is there a default locale in doctrine extensions translatable?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine-extensions

I have implemented the translatable extension. I use a Category (tree extension ) entity and a CategoryTranslation entity as shown in the documentation.
All my titles in the Category entity are in French.
I would like to translate my website in english so I add translations in locale `'en'`, for example, like this :

```
$cat = $em->getRepository('MyBundle:Category')->findOneByTitle('Nourriture');
$cat->addTranslation(new CategoryTranslation('en', 'title', 'Food'));
$em->persist($cat);
$em->flush();
```

But when I check the mywebsite.com/en, I find the Nourriture title and not the translation in english instead, while my default locale in config.yml is `'fr'`.

And when I check mywebsite.com/fr, there was no translation of my title which appears as blank. So I did the same thing that above but with `'fr'` and 'Nourriture' as a translation for the `'fr'` locale.

Then I recheck the mywebsite.com/fr and it works great I have my Nourriture title.

But it still not working for the en locale, I can't get the english translation. All happens as if the titles in my Category entity where in english, so it does not have to look for the `'en'` translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use [stof bundle](https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle) then the default locale is configured like that:

```
# app/config/config.yml
stof_doctrine_extensions:
default_locale: en_US
```

Otherwise you can set it directly in the [listener](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/TranslatableListener.php#L240)
Also you could read documentation carefully